# Menu position (admin menu) of pages

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, admin-menu, menu-order

Is there a method to change the menu position of the 'pages' post type?
When registering new custom post types, you can enter an integer in `menu_position` but how do I do this for the preregistered post types?

Can I somehow overwrite this?

PS: I need it to be 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot put this on position `5` because there is something but you can put it on `4.5` with this code :

```
add_action("admin_menu", function () {

    $GLOBALS["menu"][4.5] = $GLOBALS["menu"][20];
    unset($GLOBALS["menu"][20]);

});
```